# Column and row highlight on hover in striped table in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm using trick for CSS only highlight of table column on hover from https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/

It's work perfect, but not for striped table via

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

Highlighting not apply to upper and bottom cells in rows with background.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/615avo4v/

Please, help me fix this issue without JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to highlight only the column item or the whole row when hover

Comment: No...it wouldn't the column highlighting is done by a pseudo-element that sits behind the table itself. JS would be the best option here

Comment: @dnapierata Check the question...he's already linked that article.

Comment: @AlexNewbie col and row. Row highlights with no problem

Comment: @AlexanderSivashev, is this want you want to accomplish. see here http://jsfiddle.net/615avo4v/7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the way you set the stripped background.

Use another pseudo element, this time on the first td of the even rows, and aligned horizontally. (and with a lower z-index).

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 0;
    color: #212121;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

table>tbody>tr>td {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}


table>tbody>tr:hover {
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ffa !important;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:first-child::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    top: 0;
    left: -5000px;
    width: 10000px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -10;
}
td:hover::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffa;
    left: 0;
    top: -5000px;
    height: 10000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
            <td>col4</td>
            <td>col5</td>
            <td>col6</td>
            <td>col7</td>
            <td>col8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
            <td>col4</td>
            <td>col5</td>
            <td>col6</td>
            <td>col7</td>
            <td>col8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
            <td>col4</td>
            <td>col5</td>
            <td>col6</td>
            <td>col7</td>
            <td>col8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
            <td>col4</td>
            <td>col5</td>
            <td>col6</td>
            <td>col7</td>
            <td>col8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
            <td>col4</td>
            <td>col5</td>
            <td>col6</td>
            <td>col7</td>
            <td>col8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
            <td>col3</td>
            <td>col4</td>
            <td>col5</td>
            <td>col6</td>
            <td>col7</td>
            <td>col8</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: When I make the first column and row as header (`<th>` instead of `<td>`) the stripedness and hovering don't function well.